# Strange benchmark results for concurrent queue

Tags: c++

[In this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2bd42a80bd391f80692fc8e79f5e889a-30b7ec1164b7158ae2aa19f5f8e69331) I try to measure the average time between the pushing of an item to a concurrent queue and the popping of the item by another thread:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "tbb/concurrent_queue.h"


namespace {


void test_unbounded_queue(uint32_t iteration_count)
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::nanoseconds;

    tbb::concurrent_queue<uint32_t> unbounded_queue;

    uint32_t verify = 0;

    Clock::time_point start_time, end_time;

    std::thread consumer_thread([&]
    {
        start_time = Clock::now();

        // Active polling (100% CPU usage)
        while (true)
        {
            uint32_t n;
            if (unbounded_queue.try_pop(n))
            {
                if (n == uint32_t(-1))
                {
                    end_time = Clock::now();
                    return;
                }
                verify += n;
            }
        }
    });

    for (unsigned i = 0; i != iteration_count; ++i)
    {
        unbounded_queue.push(1);
    }

    // stop the thread
    unbounded_queue.push(uint32_t(-1));
    consumer_thread.join();

    // verify the iteration count
    if (verify != iteration_count)
    {
        std::cout << "verify: " << verify << " != " << iteration_count << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // print the results
    auto total_time_ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
    auto cost_per_pop = total_time_ns / iteration_count;
    std::cout
        << "iterations: "
        << std::setw(6) << iteration_count
        << ", total time: "
        << std::setw(9) << total_time_ns << " ns"
        << ", average time: "
        << std::setw(5) << cost_per_pop << " ns"
        << std::endl;
}


void test_bounded_queue(uint32_t iteration_count)
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::nanoseconds;

    tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<uint32_t> bounded_queue;

    uint32_t verify = 0;

    Clock::time_point start_time, end_time;

    std::thread consumer_thread([&]
    {
        start_time = Clock::now();

        while (true)
        {
            uint32_t n;
            bounded_queue.pop(n); // waits, no CPU usage
            if (n == uint32_t(-1))
            {
                end_time = Clock::now();
                return;
            }
            verify += n;
        }
    });

    for (unsigned i = 0; i != iteration_count; ++i)
    {
        bounded_queue.push(1);
    }

    // stop the thread
    bounded_queue.push(uint32_t(-1));
    consumer_thread.join();

    // verify the iteration count
    if (verify != iteration_count)
    {
        std::cout << "verify: " << verify << " != " << iteration_count << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // print the results
    auto total_time_ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
    auto cost_per_pop = total_time_ns / iteration_count;
    std::cout
        << "iterations: "
        << std::setw(6) << iteration_count
        << ", total time: "
        << std::setw(9) << total_time_ns << " ns"
        << ", average time: "
        << std::setw(5) << cost_per_pop << " ns"
        << std::endl;
}


const uint32_t min_iterations = 1u;
const uint32_t max_iterations = 128u * 1024u;


void test_bounded()
{
    std::cout << "Test bounded queue" << std::endl;
    for (uint32_t i = min_iterations; i <= max_iterations; i *= 2)
    {
        test_bounded_queue(i);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


void test_unbounded()
{
    std::cout << "Test unbounded queue" << std::endl;
    for (uint32_t i = min_iterations; i <= max_iterations; i *= 2)
    {
        test_unbounded_queue(i);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


} // namespace


int main()
{
    test_bounded();
    test_unbounded();
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
+ g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -ltbb
+ ./a.out
Test bounded queue
iterations:      1, total time:      4861 ns, average time:  4861 ns
iterations:      2, total time:      2901 ns, average time:  1450 ns
iterations:      4, total time:      3111 ns, average time:   777 ns
iterations:      8, total time:      3002 ns, average time:   375 ns
iterations:     16, total time:      3475 ns, average time:   217 ns
iterations:     32, total time:      4514 ns, average time:   141 ns
iterations:     64, total time:      6329 ns, average time:    98 ns
iterations:    128, total time:     12952 ns, average time:   101 ns
iterations:    256, total time:     53654 ns, average time:   209 ns
iterations:    512, total time:    178558 ns, average time:   348 ns
iterations:   1024, total time:    395186 ns, average time:   385 ns
iterations:   2048, total time:    886728 ns, average time:   432 ns
iterations:   4096, total time:   1865523 ns, average time:   455 ns
iterations:   8192, total time:   3535521 ns, average time:   431 ns
iterations:  16384, total time:   7044609 ns, average time:   429 ns
iterations:  32768, total time:  15743366 ns, average time:   480 ns
iterations:  65536, total time:  32278651 ns, average time:   492 ns
iterations: 131072, total time:  62466063 ns, average time:   476 ns

Test unbounded queue
iterations:      1, total time:      2952 ns, average time:  2952 ns
iterations:      2, total time:      2378 ns, average time:  1189 ns
iterations:      4, total time:      2463 ns, average time:   615 ns
iterations:      8, total time:      2874 ns, average time:   359 ns
iterations:     16, total time:      3094 ns, average time:   193 ns
iterations:     32, total time:      3542 ns, average time:   110 ns
iterations:     64, total time:      4138 ns, average time:    64 ns
iterations:    128, total time:      6380 ns, average time:    49 ns
iterations:    256, total time:     14647 ns, average time:    57 ns
iterations:    512, total time:    103661 ns, average time:   202 ns
iterations:   1024, total time:    275176 ns, average time:   268 ns
iterations:   2048, total time:    564442 ns, average time:   275 ns
iterations:   4096, total time:   1182691 ns, average time:   288 ns
iterations:   8192, total time:   2278423 ns, average time:   278 ns
iterations:  16384, total time:   4767694 ns, average time:   290 ns
iterations:  32768, total time:   9382879 ns, average time:   286 ns
iterations:  65536, total time:  18611420 ns, average time:   283 ns
iterations: 131072, total time:  34437811 ns, average time:   262 ns
```

With a high number of iterations the average time averages to 400-500 ns for the bounded queue and 200-300 ns for the unbounded queue.

For low iteration counts I would expect that "warm-up" overhead would increase the average time. However, sometimes it is only ~50 ns.

How can this be?

Comment: Those measurements are a bit pointless. First you measure time only in the consumer thread, so if you're measuring anything, it's the time to pop an element, not the total time. Also, measuring nanoseconds is daunting, even on a not-Windows system. A single context switch, and there go your nanoseconds. Further, unbounded queue polls while bounded queue blocks, which makes the comparison somewhat absurd -- they're totally different things.

Comment: Your measurements are not precise enough. Even at the highest iteration count you're measuring 34ms (unbounded) and 62ms (bounded) which are too small to be accurate, anything running in parallel on your machine can seriously disrupt these timings.

Comment: @syam However, the results become consistent around 1000 iterations and up..

Comment: Lastly, the benchmark is meaningless anyway. If it _matters_ whether you spend 50 or 500 or 5000 nanoseconds in pushing/popping, you are doing something seriously wrong. One does not queue billions and trillions of individual tasks to a queue, but one batches a few hundred/thousand tasks at a time (and, preferrably, cache-coherently). With that, the performance of the queue becomes absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: @StackedCrooked Well you're having 10% (unbounded) and 13% (bounded) of difference between highest and lowest measurements (for 2048+ iterations)  so that's not what I call very consistent, it's quite huge IMHO. YMMV though. Use enough iterations so that the running time is about 5mn, average it over several runs and you'll get a more precise benchmark.

Comment: @Damon Btw, I do measure the total time. The start_time is measured when the thread is created. The end_time is calculated if (-1) is popped. Which is pushed last.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: But, you do this inside the lambda, which is executed only after the thread is created and after the thread is scheduled -- which may very well be after the producer thread has been pushing 100 or 200 items to the queue, or maybe not. Since congestion plays a big role here, this totally invalidates all timing. And, it does not account in any way for the time (CPU time or Wall time) that it takes the producer to do its work, which is a different thing.

Comment: @Damon that is a good point. Thanks.

Comment: In practice, if you have (assuming) 1 million tasks, you would submit them in workgroups of, say, 1000 at a time. This is by all means small scale enough to properly balance work to several cores. You could as well do 10k batches. That's 1000 push/pop operations, and close to zero lock congestion (since there's 1000 times more work items than queue ops). Which means the queue overhead is totally neglegible, and you need not worry benchmarking it at all. Even if popping a work group takes **milliseconds** it hardly matters at all.

Comment: @Damon I agree. Actually, the only purpose of this benchmark is to get performance data which will help me to determine the application design.